# Вращение кругового меню по часовой стрелке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Решил сделать круговое меню, но затупил когда При клике на стрелку "вперёд" должен быть поворот по часовой стрелке со смещением всех элементов на следующую позицию. При начальной позиции на 0 градусов сверху всё работает, но нужно чтобы всё начиналось с 120 градусов: [image: ...]

В итоге сейчас сразу переходит на пятый элемент. В чём тут проблема и как её можно исправить?

```
<div class="circle-carousel">
<div class="container">
    <div class="wraper">
        <ul class="circle-container">
            <li class="circle-item selected">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-001.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="circle-item">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-002.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="circle-item">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-003.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="circle-item">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-004.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="circle-item">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-005.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="circle-item">
                <img class="circle-item-image" src="/images/thumb-003.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="circle-content">
        </div>
        <div class="circle-nav">
            <div class="circle-nav-prev">
                <a href="#">&larr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-nav-next">
                <a href="#">&rarr;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function($) {
function appendContent(elem) {
    $('.circle-content .circle-content-teaser-title').html(elem.find('.circle-item-title').text());
    $('.circle-content .circle-content-teaser-desc').html(elem.find('.circle-item-desc').text());
    $('.circle-content .circle-content-readmore').attr('href', elem.find('.circle-item-link').text());
}

var degree = 0;

function rotateElem(elem) {
    var indexCurent;
    var countElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').length;
    var indexElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').index(elem);
    
    $('.circle-container .circle-item').each(function(index) { // текущий элемент
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            indexCurent = index;
        }
    });
    
    $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').removeClass('selected');
    
    if (indexCurent < indexElem) {
        degree = degree - ((360 / countElem) * (indexElem - indexCurent));
    }
    if (indexCurent > indexElem) {
        degree = degree + ((360 / countElem) * (indexCurent - indexElem));
    }
    
    $('.circle-container').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    
    elem.addClass('selected');
}

function rotatePrev(elem) {
    $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').removeClass('selected');
    
    var countElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').length;
    var indexElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').index(elem);
    degree = degree + (360 / countElem);
    
    $('.circle-container').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    
    elem.addClass('selected');
}

function rotateNext(elem) {
    $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').removeClass('selected');
    
    var countElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').length;
    var indexElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').index(elem);
    degree = degree - (360 / countElem);
            
    $('.circle-container').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    
    elem.addClass('selected');
}

$('.circle-container .circle-item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this);
    rotateElem(elem);
    appendContent(elem);
});

$('.circle-nav .circle-nav-prev a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var prev = $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').prev();
    if (prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('.circle-container .circle-item:last-child');
    }
    rotatePrev(prev);
    appendContent(prev);
});

$('.circle-nav .circle-nav-next a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var next = $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $('.circle-container .circle-item:first-child');
    }
    rotateNext(next);
    appendContent(next);
});

appendContent($('.circle-container .circle-item.selected'));
```

});

Comment: Приложи css стили к коду, чтобы можно было воспроизвести полноценно всё

Answer (score 0):

> В чём тут проблема и как её можно исправить?

Основная проблема - это недопонимание назначения сочетаний клавиш <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. Данная комбинация существует для мультиплицирования, в целях ускорения написания кода. Но, сто́ит чётко представлять предмет копирования и быть уверенным в его работоспособности, дабы не множить возможные проблемы и ошибки.

Зачастую проще написать собственное решение "с нуля" под свои задачи:

```js
const OFFSET = 120; // Коррекция начального угла
const CARОUSEL = $('ul');
const NODES = $(CARОUSEL).children('li');
const LENGTH = $(NODES).length;
$(NODES).each((ind, el) => { $(el).css('--round', (1 / LENGTH) * ind + (1 / 360) * OFFSET) });

$('#reset').on('click', () => { $(CARОUSEL).css('--angle', ''); $(NODES).each((ind, el) => { $(el).toggleClass('select', ind > 0 ? false : true) }) });
$('#prev').on('click', () => fNav(1));
$('#next').on('click', () => fNav(-1));
$(CARОUSEL).on('wheel', () => { event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); fNav(Math.sign(event.deltaY) * -1) });
$(CARОUSEL).on('click', () => { let target = event.target.closest('li'); if (target) fNav(0, target) });

function fNav(dir, target) {
  let curr = parseFloat($(CARОUSEL).css('--angle'));
  let active = $(CARОUSEL).children('li.select');
  let actInd = $(NODES).index(active);
  let diff = actInd - $(NODES).index(target);
  if (target) {
    dir = Math.sign(diff) * (Math.abs(diff) > Math.floor(LENGTH / 2) ? Math.abs(diff) - LENGTH : Math.abs(diff));
  } else {
    target = dir > 0 ? actInd-- > 0 ? $(NODES).eq(actInd) : $(NODES).eq(LENGTH - 1) : actInd++ < LENGTH - 1 ? $(NODES).eq(actInd) : $(NODES).eq(0);
  }
  $(active).toggleClass('select', false);
  $(target).toggleClass('select', true);
  $(CARОUSEL).css('--angle', curr + (1 / LENGTH) * dir);
}
```

```css
ul {
  --angle: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px; width: 250px;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 2px #0008);
}

li {
  --round: 0;
  position: absolute; left: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(calc((var(--round) + var(--angle)) * 1turn));
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

li > div {
  position: absolute; left: 50%;
  display: grid; place-items: center;
  height: 2.5em; width: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(calc((var(--round) + var(--angle)) * -1turn));
  font: 16px/1em 'Arial Black';
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px #fa0;
  transition: .25s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li > div:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 5px #fa0;
  transition: .125s ease-in-out, transform 1s ease-out;
}
li.select > div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 3em #fa0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button { font: 22px/1em 'Arial Black'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev">&#9664;</button><button id="reset">&#10060;</button><button id="next">&#9654;</button>
<ul>
  <li class="select"><div>1</div></li>
  <li><div>2</div></li>
  <li><div>3</div></li>
  <li><div>4</div></li>
  <li><div>5</div></li>
  <li><div>6</div></li>
  <li><div>7</div></li>
  <li><div>8</div></li>
  <li><div>9</div></li>
  <li><div>10</div></li>
  <li><div>11</div></li>
  <li><div>12</div></li>
</ul>
```

Перебор осуществляется колесом мыши, кнопками навигации или нажатием на соответствующий пункт.

Это же решение на "чистом" JavaScript - https://codepen.io/UModeL/full/bGzLwmZ.